# Vertically aligning CSS :before and :after content

Tags: css, css-content

I am trying to centre the link with the image, but can't seem to move the content vertically in any way.

```
<h4>More Information</h4>
<a href="#" class="pdf">File Name</a>
```

The icon is 22 x 22px

```
.pdf {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.pdf:before {
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
    content: url(../img/icon/pdf_small.png);
}
.pdf:after {
    content: " ( .pdf )";
    font-size: 10px;
}
.pdf:hover:after {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Consider using flex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22218694/435605 - the answer is for text but works on all elements.

Comment: Thanks to CSS3's [substring matching attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings), you can now do `a[href$=".pdf"] { … }` and not even need the class.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer for vertically centering content of :before/:after pseudo-elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524161/470749

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Answered my own question after reading your advice on the vertical-align CSS attribute. Thanks for the tip!

```
.pdf:before {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    content: url(../img/icon/pdf_small.png);
    vertical-align: -50%;
}
```

Comment: Nice. What worked for me was vertical-align:super;

Comment: This vertical-align in % with negative values is awesome. Don't know before.

Answer (score 35):

You can also use tables to accomplish this, like:

```
.pdf {
  display: table;
}
.pdf:before {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ar9fadd0/2/

EDIT:
You can also use flex to accomplish this:

```
.pdf {
  display: flex;
}
.pdf:before {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ctqk0xq1/1/

Comment: neither of these fiddles work on Chrome 52

Comment: both of them work for me on Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) (Linux)

Comment: neither works on OSX. http://imgur.com/bqUQ09X

Comment: the question was about vertically aligning :before and :after elements and thats what the fiddles do, also in your screenshot

Comment: "I am trying to centre the link with the image" that isn't done in either example or my screenshot

Comment: Works as a charm nowadays. Used for a tiny icon that indicates a master-detail row in a table and aligns perfectly in the middle dynamically (resizing the window makes the <tr> element larger and smaller and the icon stays vertically centered (chrome))

Answer (score 31):

I'm no CSS expert, but what happens if you put `vertical-align: middle;` into your `.pdf:before` directive?

Comment: Awesome, middle did not work so I had to use a negative percentage instead, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Glad to help. Did "middle" do nothing, or something-but-not-what-you-wanted?

Answer (score 14):

I think a cleaner approach is to inherit the vertical alignment:

In html:

```
<div class="shortcut"><a href="#">Download</a></div>
```

And in css:

```
.shortcut {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.shortcut > a:after {
    vertical-align: inherit;
{
```

This way the icon will align properly in any resolution/font-size combination. Great for use with icon fonts.

Comment: Perfect. Simple and elegant

Answer (score 11):

Using flexboxes did the trick for me:

```css
.pdf:before {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me:

```
.pdf::before {
    content: url('path/to/image.png');
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Messing around with the line-height attribute should do the trick. I haven't tested this, so the exact value may not be right, but start with 1.5em, and tweak it in 0.1 increments until it lines up.

```
.pdf{ line-height:1.5em; }
```

Comment: that should do the trick for text-content!

Answer (score 5):

I spent a good amount of time trying to work this out today, and couldn't get things working using line-height or vertical-align. The easiest solution I was able to find was to set the <a/> to be relatively positioned so it would contain absolutes, and the :after to be positioned absolutely taking it out of the flow.

```
a{
    position:relative;
    padding-right:18px;
}
a:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:url(image.png);
}
```

The after image seemed to automatically center in that case, at least under Firefox/Chrome. Such may be a bit sloppier for browsers not supporting :after, due to the excess spacing on the <a/>.

Answer (score 4):

I just found a pretty neat solution, I think. The trick is to set the `line-height` of image (or any content) `height`.

text

Using CSS:

```
div{
  line-height: 26px; /* height of the image in #submit span:after */
}

span:after{
    content: url('images/forward.png');
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

That would probably also work without the span.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Here is what I did. Since the element I was trying to center vertically had height = 60px, I managed to center it vertically using:

top: calc(50% - 30px);