# Vertically centering content of :before/:after pseudo-elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this picture:

[image]

I have an image (as part of a slideshow) wrapped in a div, and with :before and :after pseudo-elements, I display two controls to move onto the next (>>) or previous (<<) images of the slideshow.

So far, I have this:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  display:block;
  height: 100%;
  content: "stuff";
  position:absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I can't, however, center the content of the pseudo-elements, the text appears like this:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve? If not, what would be the most semantic workaround?
I do not want to center the element itself, only its content. I'd prefer to have the element stretched to 100% height.

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4u/

**Edit2:** Also, the img is liquid/fluid, the height of the div/img are unknown, and the width is set to 800px and `max-width` to 80%.

Comment: Are you sure that's your code? (see http://jsfiddle.net/RLccx/)

Comment: I thought that pseudoelements weren't allowed on empty elements (like img or input...)

Comment: `IMG` can't have after and before, anyway he obviously used maybe div. This is just an example.

Comment: @dfsq the devil is in the details. Especially when dealing with more complex layouts, the specifics are important.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I apologize! I did indeed wrap the img in a div, and applied the pseudo-elements to the div instead. I'm not at home, so I wrote this from what I could remember, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Assuming your element is not an `<img>` (because pseudo elements are not allowed on self-closing elements), let's suppose it's a `<div>`, so a way could be:

```css
div {
    height: 100px ;
    line-height: 100px;
}
div:before, div:after {
    content: "";
    ...
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: ...;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

If you cannot change the line-height of the div, another way is:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}
div:before, div:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    content: "";
    width: ...
}
```

Otherwise, just place the indicators as a background in center position.

Comment: The first solution is not possible because the height of the div is unknown, and the second isn't possible either because, as I stated, I don't want to center the whole pseudo-element (as you did with `top: 50%`), only its content.

Comment: @dcastro your controls `>>` and `<<` are text or they are two images?

Comment: I'm just using dummy `lorem ipsum` for now, but I think I'll go with either css or icon fonts to generate the symbols. Almost certainly, I won't use images.

Comment: unless, if using images would make this situation possible, I guess I would give it a thought and use images instead.

Comment: using images as background just set the background-position to center

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll try that in a few hours and get back to you.

Answer (score 49):

Using flex in the pseudo element's css it is rather easy:

```
.parent::after {
  content: "Pseudo child text";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/w408o7cq/

Comment: Beat me to it.  This should be the accepted answer, if flexbox is an option.

Comment: This will have the after-content overlapping the parent.

Comment: @robx overlapping the parent is actually the idea... (see the OPs picture)

Comment: Perfect answer. In my scenario, other answer isn't working and this really helped me.

Answer (score 9):

Using flex box, you should set a fixed width and height in the parent first then

```
div::after {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect - short and concise. Though for me `height:100%` was not required.

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm late for the party but this simple flex solution worked like a charm for me in case it helps any of you.

```
.main-div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.my-div-name:before, .my-div-name:after {
    /* This content will be vertically centered with the attributes of the main-div */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can do this without resorting to images.** (Sometimes you can't, e.g. using font icons inside :before or :after).

```
div {
   position: relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}

div:before, div:after {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);

   height:20000px;
   line-height:20000px;

   content: ">>";
}
```

Admittedly, it's a bit cheeky to use 20000px If your div will ever be larger than that, just increase the px.

**In your case, you have an image inside the div, so hit that image with display:block** (images don't default to display:block)

Here's the updated fiddle for your particular case. http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4u/56/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of creating next and previous controls, using :before and :after pseudo-elements.  Along with border trick to create triangles for previous/next buttons.  It does not give you an area 100% of height to click, but if you make the triangle (arrows) a big enough size it should make up for that.

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div:before, div:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display:block;
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  }

div:before {
  top: 40%; left: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 50px solid blue; 
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

div:after {
  top: 40%; right: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent; 
  border-left: 50px solid blue; 
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

Here is the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleriddler/rPPMf/