# How to vertically (middle position) align pseudo-element 'before' for LI element

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align pseudo-element `li:before`, without using margin, I've tried to include `vertical-align: middle;` in the `ul.nav-menu-list li:hover:before, .nav-menu-list li:focus:before`, but it's not working.

Bellow is my code or [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bayxxey3/5/):

```
.nav-menu-list>li>a {
    font-family: 'Pribambas', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

ul.nav-menu-list li a {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-left: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.nav-menu-list li:hover:before, .nav-menu-list li:focus:before {
    content: '-';
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.nav-menu-list li a:hover, ul.nav-menu-list li a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #a2a2a2;
}
```

Comment: Of course it is not working, because `vertical-align` doesn’t apply to `block` elements.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer for vertically centering content of :before/:after pseudo-elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524161/470749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit* I just see that you don't want to use margin. Well I tried :)

This will work as you want it to work, just set display to inline-block and give it a margin-bottom of 6px: http://jsfiddle.net/bayxxey3/8/

```
ul.nav-menu-list li:hover:before, .nav-menu-list li:focus:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #000;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I had a little bit wrong the CSS, the `content '';` has to be a block like here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bayxxey3/5/), but line-height isn't working

Comment: another way is to use `background-image` instead of `content` [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bayxxey3/7/) , for class `ul.nav-menu-list li:hover, .nav-menu-list li:focus` but I would not prefer this way, but I'm struggling to make it work, lol

Comment: @ValeriCrudu I have made a new fiddle. If you don't want to have any content you have to treat the `before` as an element.

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
 .nav-menu-list>li {
     position: relative;
 }
 ul.nav-menu-list li:hover:before, .nav-menu-list li:focus:before {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -3px;
 }
```

to achieve vertical align

Answer (score 1):

set `vertical-align: middle;` on the `a` as well, and change the `:before` to `display:inline-block`. Now you have two "elements" both inline-block and middle aligned.

`vertical-align` needs elements working together to create an align. `Block` doesn't play along.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution for this kind of need with using an absolute top position set to 50% and negative translateY value set to -50%.
Parent element must have a relative position. Explanation [here](https://www.howtoonlinetips.com/vertically-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Please see the modified CSS code from the question and please notice that you don't need `clear: both` or `line-height: 28px`

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-menu-list>li>a {
    font-family: 'Pribambas', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

ul.nav-menu-list li a {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-left: 60px;
    color: #000;
}

ul.nav-menu-list li {
    position: relative;  
}

ul.nav-menu-list li:hover:before, .nav-menu-list li:focus:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #000;
    /* clear: both; */
    /* line-height: 28px; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul.nav-menu-list li a:hover, ul.nav-menu-list li a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #a2a2a2;
}
```

```html
      <ul class="nav-menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
      </ul>
```