# Vertically centering pseudo element text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've been trying to figure out how to *vertically center* an `::after` pseudo-element that contains text (a `content` attribute).

**Previous questions**: there are some **[previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523927/vertically-centering-content-of-before-after-pseudo-elements)** which address this, but none of the solutions seem to work for this simple case.

Here I basically have a simple `DIV` that should function as a "next" button.  It contains a simple right arrow (Unicode `0x203A`).

The markup is basically just:

```
<div class = "next-button"></div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.next-button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.next-button::after {
    content: "\203A";
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 0;
```

}

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/me6a3nq2/

So, I've been trying various things to center this.  Firstly, `vertical-align:middle` doesn't work here.  Another CSS trick is to set the `line-height` of the parent element equal to the `height` of the parent element.  However, this doesn't seem to work either.

I can add `position:relative` to `next-button::after`, and then adjust `top` accordingly, but this won't exactly center the arrow unless I know the exact height of the arrow, which may change or vary across browsers.

I also tried using a common CSS method, which is to use `translateY`, [as specified here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/). I usually have very good success with this method:

```
.next-button::after {
    content: "\203A";
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

But even this doesn't work with the pseudo element.  It appears to move the arrow, but it places it off-centered towards the bottom, at least on Chrome:

[image]

I also notice, when using the Chrome Inspector tool, that the arrow itself, which is basically just a character of text, seems to have "padding" automatically above and below it, and that the "above" padding is seemingly larger than the below padding, causing the arrow to be uncentered vertically:

[image]

...but, I can't really tell why this padding exists, nor do I seem to have any control of it.  I thought it might be `line-height`, so I set `line-height` to `0`, but that had no effect.

So, I'm out of ideas.  I'm thinking I may need to give up on using a pseudo element and just make the arrow inside a nested DIV.

**Question:** Is there any way to vertically align a pseudo element?  (And also, what is the cause of the "padding" above and below of the text in the pseudo element `content`?)

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Works just fine -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/LhthmtL3/

Comment: And this -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/LhthmtL3/1/

Comment: @Abhitalks it only seems to be centered beacause it's smaller, but it's not :/

Comment: @Abhitalks, it doesn't work.  The example you posted just happens to appear centered.  But change the height to `100px` and you see it's not centered. https://jsfiddle.net/LhthmtL3/3/

Comment: @Siler: agreed, my bad. It seems to be the internal ascender height on the character, which I missed.

Comment: the use of 2 pseudo and font-size set on parent would help https://jsfiddle.net/me6a3nq2/5/

Comment: @GCyrillus - It looks like you should answer this question. That's a really nice technique.  I'd really appreciate an explanation as to *how* this works as well. I'll probably also delete my answer because it now seems to be incorrect

Comment: @Danield not sure it is an answer but, if 2 inline-block elements are side by side, you can use vertical-align to center them to each other., because of letter and font-family used, the second vertical-align property needs to be tuned. test: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPWExj an icon or an image should be used here to master the layout :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's OK for you,  set `line-height: 65px;`:

That's how I do it in my Projects. But if the height changes you will have to change the line-height as well. The problem is that these Symbols are not verticly centered at their center of look, but on the baseline for text. I don't think there is a better solution to this.

```css
.next-button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.next-button::after {
  font-family: Arial;
  content: "\203A";
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="next-button"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like it is still not centered and aligned somewhat towards the middle. Same issue as mine I guess. I too didn't know why I was downvoted.

Comment: @PraveenKumar its centered in all my Browsers, wich one do you use?

Comment: @PraveenKumar well it's centered on my Chrome.. can you make a screenshot?

Comment: Oh it looks like we have diffrent fonts. I set the font to Arial for Demo, should be centered now?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to vertically align a pseudo element?

Yes, and all of the ways you describe actually work.

Take for example the `transform` method - just add a border to the character - and you can clearly see that the character - which includes the entire area in the red border - is centered  [(Fiddle Demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/me6a3nq2/4/)

So the problem here is that the character glyph itself isn't centered - and that's probably for a good reason - just like an underscore character isn't centered either.

So this actually has nothing to do with pseudo elements but rather the specific character you have chosen to center.

You'll either have to *manually adjust* the character so that it centers **OR** use a different character for your arrow.

Comment: I see what you're saying about the centering of the glyph itself.  But regardless, this seems to still be dependent on the size/height of the text itself.  Like if I change the font-size to `1em`, suddenly it's not centered: https://jsfiddle.net/me6a3nq2/6/

Answer (score 0):

Although `line-height` will do the job, I found out another solution.!!

Just give `vertical-align:sub` to the `pseudo element` of `.next-button`.

Here is the fiddle.

```css
    .next-button {
     position: absolute;
     height: 70px;
     line-height: 70px;
     text-align: center;
     background: black;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .next-button::after {
     content: "\203A";
     color: white;
     font-size: 3em;
     line-height: 0;
      vertical-align: sub;
   }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class = "next-button"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox in CSS3.

```
display: flex,
justify-content: center  // or you can also use space-around, it all depends.

// other ways:
align-item: center  or;
align-self: center
```

Here a link to a example: [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css?rq=1)