# Unable to center :before image in div with other content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center a image in a :before pseudo element. I've found a few questions about it here (and other places), but unfortunately I'm unable to make it work with those tips.

I want to center the image to come between the to lines of text:

[image]

A js-fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kaze72/vb5z4/1/

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="welcomeHeader">         
        <h3>Welcome</h3>
        <h6>Adam Testorsson</h6>
    </div>
    <p>other stuff</p>
</div>
```

Main css:

```
.welcomeHeader {
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.welcomeHeader:before {
    background-image: url('http://www.ronnebybloggen.se/pics/apml.png');
    /* background-position: 0px -20px; */
    display: inline-block;
    content: ' ';
    vertical-align: -50%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align` won't work as you're trying to allign it with two block level headings...and in any case (-505) is invalid in that property.

Comment: I got -50% from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833027/vertically-aligning-css-before-and-after-content , but the tip does not work for me.

Comment: Thanks to all for suggestions and comments :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There it is : http://jsfiddle.net/vb5z4/5/

This solution is based on `background-position` : **I made the :before element to make 100% height of its parent, and set its background to be at its vertical center**.

```
.welcomeHeader {


   padding-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; // Need the parent to be relative
}

.welcomeHeader:before {
    position: absolute; // :before becomes absolute
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('http://www.ronnebybloggen.se/pics/apml.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; // don't repeat background
    background-position: left center;
    display: inline-block;
    content: ' ';

    width: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -22px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

* {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

The good point in this technique is that even if you change the background, it will still be vertically centered, no need to fix a negative margin (that depends on image height).

Comment: +1 clean approach. Negative margins are not required, however. absolutely positioned elements must ideally be positioned using top/left.

Answer (score 0):

Added `position:relative;` to `.welcomeHeader`.
Remove margins and add these in `.welcomeHeader:before`

```
position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -6px;
```

I have updated you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vb5z4/4/). Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you still wish to use the pseduo element it would be preferable to use absolute position on that.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/vb5z4/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="welcomeHeader">         
        <h3>Welcome</h3>
        <h6>Adam Testorsson</h6>
    </div>
    <p>other stuff</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.welcomeHeader {
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.welcomeHeader:before {
    background-image: url('http://www.ronnebybloggen.se/pics/apml.png');
    /* background-position: 0px -20px; */
    content: ' ';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -6px; /* half of height */
    left:0; /* or someother required value */

}

* {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 5px;
}

h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```