# Vertical align :after element

Tags: css

I've tried the various responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833027/vertically-aligning-css-before-and-after-content) but no luck.

I need to vertical align an after element:

```
content: "";
width: 30px;
height: 15px;
background: transparent url('/img/test.png') no-repeat;
float: right;
border: 1px solid red;
```

This does not work:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Nor does:

```
vertical-align: -50%;
```

Comment: Float and vertical align don't work together :)

Comment: Ah thanks, unfortunately when I take this off and use inline display, it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

From those answers linked to, the `vertical-align:inherit;` on the element worked for me when I set the parent element to `vertical-align:top;`, nothing else seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` on the parent element and `display:inline-block` on the pseudo `:after`

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #CCC;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box:after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/tianes/zhwL3rrq/